# Laravel eloquent relation multiple models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I've got 4 different models. But don't quiet got the hang on the relationship I'm supposed to use.
Models: `County`, `Municipality`, `Postal` and `Zip`.
Table and primary keys are correctly set in each model.

In `County` model I've added:

```
public function municipality() {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Municipality');
}
```

In `Municipality` model I've added:

```
public function postal() {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Postal');
}
```

And in `Postal` model I've added:

```
public function zip() {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Zip');
}
```

I have tested this:
`County::findOrFail(1)->municipality;` and it works.
But how would I get the postals that belongs to that specific municipality?

I can't do this: `County::findOrFail(1)->municipality->postal;` which I thought I could. But I can see I don't have the hang of it yet.

How would I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Database structure: http://pastebin.com/ts0D5juq

Answer (score 0):

You missed something:

```
County::findOrFail(1)->municipality;
```

Here you have the `municipality` field of county not the actual object.

You have to use your functions:

```
County::findOrFail(1)->municipality()->postal();
```

Comment: When I try to use the above (functions) I get an error:
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::postal()`

Comment: Try this: `County::findOrFail(1)->municipality()->first()->postal()->first();`

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that does the trick. So I have to use `first()` after each relation method?

Comment: Well this use the Laravel query system, I would recommend you to read carefully this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships